# What vim plugin does leetcode use to auto-close parenthesis?

Tags: vim

I like the way leetcode vim auto close braces.

1. It closes when I type `"` `'` `(` `{` `[` which can be done with simple vim map
2. When I try to close one more tim it doesn't add another `"` `'` `)` `}` `]`  and skip. Most vim plugin works like this.
3. When I press { and enter, it automatically add new line for my code and indent for me.
   To be specific

```
{<cursor>}
```

when I press enter, it becomes

```
{
     cursor
}
```

I don't know which plugin works like leetcode vim.

Plus, what is some vanilla vim way to solve 2nd issue?

I tried to analyze by looking at plugins but it was too complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These vanilla vim mapping will do what you are looking for, especially the last two is interesting.

```
inoremap " ""<left>
inoremap ' ''<left>
inoremap ( ()<left>
inoremap [ []<left>
inoremap { {}<left>
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<ESC>O
inoremap {;<CR> {<CR>};<ESC>O
```

This autocomplete in `insert` mode, provided `set paste` is not set. When we don't want the mapping, we need to escape it using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> before typing the mapped char like `( {` etc.

Answer (score 1):

@dlmeetei's answer would print ()) when I type (), and escape mapping would be burdensome.

So, I improved the answer above, by creating a simple function, so please correct and improve my idea.

```
"" check whether current charcter (on cursor) equals parameter
"" then decide whether to put new parenthesis
func! AutoClose(...)
    let cur = getline(".")[col(".")]
    if cur != a:1
        if a:1 == "'" || a:1 == '"'
            execute "normal!a".a:1.a:1
        else
            execute "normal!a".a:1
        endif
        execute "normal!h"
    else
        execute "normal!l"
    endif 
endfunc

inoremap ( ()<left> 
inoremap [ []<left> 
inoremap { {}<left> 
inoremap ) <ESC>:call AutoClose(')') <CR>a 
inoremap ] <ESC>:call AutoClose(']') <CR>a 
inoremap } <ESC>:call AutoClose('}') <CR>a 
inoremap " <ESC>:call AutoClose('"') <CR>a 
inoremap ' <ESC>:call AutoClose("'") <CR>a 
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<ESC>O 
inoremap {;<CR> {<CR>};<ESC>O
```